# Trying to parse 0.0000 number to SQL

Tags: vb.net, types, floating-point, decimal

I am trying to parse a 0.0000 number (i.e 0.0125) from a CSV file into an SQL database.

The trouble is that by the time it hits my database. It has turned into a normal number!

Here is my dB structure:

```
CREATE TABLE RatesImport
(
"CallType" VarChar(30),
"ChargeCode" VarChar(30),
"Destination" VarChar(30),
"TariffUsed" VarChar(30),
"Peak" Real,
```

The field I am having trouble with is "Peak"

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
    '--First create a datatable with the same cols as CSV file, the cols order in both should be same
    Dim table As New DataTable()

    table.Columns.Add("CallType", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("ChargeCode", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Destination", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("TariffUsed", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Peak", GetType(Double))
    table.Columns.Add("OffPeak", GetType(Double))
    table.Columns.Add("Weekend", GetType(Double))
    table.Columns.Add("Setup", GetType(Double))
    table.Columns.Add("MinimumCharge", GetType(Double))
    table.Columns.Add("ChargeCap", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("InitialUnits", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("InitialCharge", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("InitialPeak", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("InitialOffPeak", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("InitialWeekend", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("BillingUnit", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("MinimumUnits", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("RateType", GetType(String))



    'open file dialog and store filename'
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim strFileName As String

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\Barry\Documents\Indigo Billing dB\Daisy Call Rates"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

    End If
    strFileName = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName
    If strFileName <> "" Then


        '--TextField Parser is used to read the files 
        Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(openFileDialog1.FileName)


        MessageBox.Show("New Rate Card Loaded...", "Indigo Billing", _
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)


        parser.Delimiters = New String() {","} ' fields are separated by comma
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True ' each of the values is enclosed with double quotes
        parser.TrimWhiteSpace = True

        '--First line is skipped , its the header
        parser.ReadLine()

        '-- Add all the rows to datatable
        Do Until parser.EndOfData = True
            table.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields())
        Loop

        '--Create SQL query
        Dim strSql As String = "INSERT INTO DaisyRatesImport (CallType,ChargeCode,Destination,TariffUsed,Peak,OffPeak,Weekend,Setup,MinimumCharge,ChargeCap,InitialUnits,InitialCharge,InitialPeak,InitialOffPeak,InitialWeekend,BillingUnit,MinimumUnits,RateType) VALUES (@CallType,@ChargeCode,@Destination,@TariffUsed,@Peak,@OffPeak,@Weekend,@Setup,@MinimumCharge,@ChargeCap,@InitialUnits,@InitialCharge,@InitialPeak,@InitialOffPeak,@InitialWeekend,@BillingUnit,@MinimumUnits,@RateType)"
        Dim SqlconnectionString As String = "server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=Test; integrated security=yes"
        Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(SqlconnectionString)

            Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSql, connection) ' create command objects and add parameters
            With cmd.Parameters

                .Add("@CallType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "CallType")
                .Add("@ChargeCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "ChargeCode")
                .Add("@Destination", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "Destination")
                .Add("@TariffUsed", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "TariffUsed")
                .Add("@Peak", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Peak")
                .Add("@OffPeak", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "OffPeak")
```

With the line .Add("@Peak", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Peak") as it is above the code works, but rounds the number to a 0 or 1.

But if I change to .Add("@Peak", SqlDbType.Real, "Peak"), so the type matches my database Column - I get the following error.

Conversion from string "Peak" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Update:

I have a column called Peak in my CSV file, below is an example of the data in that column:

- Peak
- 0.0822
- 0.0678
- 0.1232
- 0.2645
- 0.1428
- 0.2673

Comment: Please post the first few lines of the file you are trying to import.

Comment: The problem is with your database. As I can see, Peek is INT in you database. You need to change to store decimal.

Comment: Does the CSV file contain a header row with "Peak" in the column name?

Comment: Even though you are calling `ReadLine` first before your loop, which seems like it ought to skip the first line (containing the string "Peak"), it must not be.  You'd need to trace through the code to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to convert the string "Peak" to SqlDbType.Real, you need to read the values from  the datatable you have filled before. Right now you are filling your database with the strings "CallType","ChargeCode",..."Peak",... but not the values.

Comment: I am not sure I understand - I am not pulling these values from a database, they are coming from a CSV file and I am trying to import into a dB

Comment: @user3580480 he is saying that `.Add("@Peak", SqlDbType.Int, 5, "Peak")` is trying to add the literal "Peak" as a string rather than the **value** of peak read from the CSV.  The CSV contains TEXT, so you need to convert to the proper data type before adding to the DB

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix, that makes sense as CSV is a text file :) How do I convert the values. Could you provide a code example? Thanks

Comment: `Convert.ToInteger`, `Convert.ToDouble`, `Convert.ToSingle` or to be safe and test the data integrity,  `Double.TryParse`, `Integer.TryParse` etc.  also check the args which `Parameters.Add` requires.  I suspect you could benefit (greatly) from `Option Strict`